# Ford 2006 xlt 3.0 transmission slips out

Tags: ford, transmission

Any idea of the problem.  SUV warms up and I drive 3 blocks and I loose drive and reverse.  I let it sit for 30 minutes and I can drive again for 3 blocks and then loose drive and reverse.  I stopped there and had the vehicle towed home.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this an Explorer?

Comment: If the engine is still running (and it sounds like it is) then it's most likely a transmission issue - I'd be inclined to think there might be overheating ATF issues. Have you checked the transmission fluid level/condition?